# Socket.io nodejs https CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, socket.io, nodes

I have a website with SSL installed which is working fine. When I call socket server I am getting `Mixed Content` warning on browser.

To resolve that, I have generated certificate files using below command.

`openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert`

And added them in my code

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

//openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
const httpServer = createServer({
    key: readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: readFileSync('./server.cert'),
});

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});

httpServer.listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user connected', socket.id);
});
```

On the client website i am getting `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error when calling to socket
server

I have tried few options to solve this so far,

1. Added `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` on top of socket server file.
2. Added `rejectUnauthorized : false` in socket options

```
const httpServer = createServer({
    key: readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: readFileSync('./server.cert'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```

I am still getting `CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the certificate generated for main domain using lets encrypt. I have tried that approach first but it gave me

`Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

That means there's a problem on certificate format.

I have re generated the certificates for the domain. Added them while creating server.
This is how working code looks.

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const httpServer = createServer({
    key: readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem'),
    cert: readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem')
});

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});

httpServer.listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user connected', socket.id);
});
```